# Задача вывести максимум и минимум в функции. Не пойму почему не работает цикл for

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему цикл не перебирает массив.

```js
let max = array[0] ;
let min = array[0] ;
function hightAndLow(numbers){    
     let array = numbers.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max) {
        max = array[i];
      }
        if (array[i] < min) {
        min = array[i];
      }
    }

    alert("Max is " + max);
  alert("Min is " + min);
}
  hightAndLow('1 2 3 4 5');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  let array = numbers.split(' ').map(i => +i);
  let max = array[0];
  let min = array[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max) {
      max = array[i];
    }
    if (array[i] < min) {
      min = array[i];
    }
  }
  return {min, max};
}
console.log(highAndLow('1 2 3 4 5'));
```

Comment: А почему предыдущий код не работал? Зачем нужно добавлять map?  Если есть ссылка где почитать, буду благодарен

Comment: Вы переменные мин и макс не там обьявили

Comment: @RavenTheX, корректнее будет сказать что в том месте array ещё не существует, т.к. он обявляется только внутри функции. [Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). А `map` добавлен для того что бы строки к числу привести

Comment: Спасибо! Функция же имеет доступ к внешним переменным, почему же не может их изменить?

Comment: @Moncer Функция имеет доступ, но вы пытаетесь переменным присвоить значение которого ещё нет и [ошибка вам об этом прямо говорит](https://i.imgur.com/tVrRH1C.png)

Comment: @Ein Спасибо, понял свою глупую ошибку